# Not able to give variables having absolute path values in outputvariable in maven-dependency-plugin

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-plugin, pom.xml

In `outputvariable` tag of maven-dependency-plugin, if i give a variable(tag), then it takes as relative path to the project location. i want it to consider as absolute path instead of relative path, how to achieve this?

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${somepath}\lib\ext</outputDirectory>
                    <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

If i declare a variable  `somepath`  with this value  `file:/u01/xxx/yyy` 
 and used in maven-dependency-plugin   `${somepath}/lib/ext`, then it tries to create the folder relative to my project location and results in error

i want to give a absolute path in the  `outputDirectory`  tag, how do i achieve it?

Comment: Can you try with the latest version (2.8 currently). As far as I know and could experience, outputDirectory is not relative.

Comment: "outputDirectory - String - Sets the output directory RELATIVE to the root of the root directory of the assembly. For example, "log" will put the specified files in the log directory, directly beneath the root of the archive. " taken from - maven reference

Comment: True for the assembly plugin, not the dependency one ;)

Comment: I have tried and it is indeed relative,  from this link it says that default value is "Default value is: ${project.build.directory}/dependency." which means the path is relative rite?
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#outputDirectory

Comment: That just means the default value is ${projectDir}/target/dependency.

Comment: Just tried your config (exact same) with a hardcoded value (c:/tmp for me, under Windows). Works fine.

Comment: yes i agree with that. The thing is if i give value there it is taken as relative to the project location .i.e., relative to ${project.build.directory}. so anything i give in outputDirectory tag, it will append to ${project.build.directory}. as a result of this not able to give absolute path via varible.

Comment: No i think u have given the absolute path directly(which worked for me also), can you give this value(c:/tmp) in variable and use that in outputDirectory tag.

i mean <somePath> file:/tmp</somepath> and try

Comment: Just tried, works fine too. Can you give the full (or at least all the relevant parts) of you pom, plus the output of the dependency plugin execution?

Comment: BTW, file: looks weird to me. I guess it does not recognize it correctly. Just try /tmp instead.

Comment: "file:" is used so that path is compatible to across windows and unix platforms. so i have used it. it works in other cases. only in this tag its giving issues

Comment: Well that seems to be the issue here. My best guess it that the dep plugin tries to be smart guessing if the directory is absolute or relative, and "file:" does not fit correctly. You might either not use that protocol or open an issue in the plugin JIRA project.